# Unable to resolve module ./InputToolbar from node_modules\react-native-gifted-chat\lib\GiftedChat.js:

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <GiftedChat
  messages={messages}
  bottomOffset={49}
  onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
  renderInputToolbar={renderInputToolbar}
  user={{
    _id: 1,
  }}
/>
  
  {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>userSignout()}><Text>Don't have an account? Create one</Text></TouchableOpacity>  */}
</View>
```

)
}

export default ChatScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please solve with the update of gifted chat version thank you